# What query will show which athletes did not receive any votes? (Self-join)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have spent a lot of time on this and cannot figure it out.

I created a database for this, which shows which athlete another athlete has voted to win:

Here is my athlete table:

[image: My database (athlete table)]

Here is my team table:

[image: My database (team table)]

I have a separate table for team, and athlete. (Athlete includes votesForId)
I need a query that is specifically for this self-join table.

I am trying to figure out a query to show which athletes did not receive any votes by the other athletes. I have tried quite a few things and to be honest at this point I have no idea which way this is supposed to go. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
If anyone needs this answer in the future, this was my completed answer I figured out (I added concat for my own purposes):

```
SELECT CONCAT(voter.athleteFirstName, ' ', voter.athleteLastName) AS [Did Not Recieve Any Votes]
FROM athlete AS voter LEFT JOIN athlete AS recipent ON voter.athleteID = recipent.votesforId
WHERE recipent.athleteId IS NULL
ORDER BY voter.athleteFirstName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs this answer in the future, this was my completed answer I figured out (I added concat for my own purposes):

```
SELECT CONCAT(voter.athleteFirstName, ' ', voter.athleteLastName) AS [Did Not 
Recieve Any Votes]
FROM athlete AS voter LEFT JOIN athlete AS recipent ON voter.athleteID = 
recipent.votesforId
WHERE recipent.athleteId IS NULL
ORDER BY voter.athleteFirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a table of athletes and a separate one for votes.  Then you would use:

```
select a.*
from athletes a
where not exists (select 1
                  from votes v
                  where v.votesForId = a.athleteId
                 );
```

Of course, this could be one table, but it would make more sense to me if there were two.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! So, I am actually still fairly new to SQL and am learning it in school (we haven't learned 'where not exists' yet). I made this database over a period of a few labs. I have to keep everything in 1 table so that it is a self-join type of table. Is there a different type of answer for this you could assist me with with those things in mind? :)

Comment: @RachelD . . . It seems odd to me that an athlete has only one vote.  However, if you use the same table in the outer and inner query, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get athletes that do not have their id in the votesForId column.

```
SELECT *
FROM athlete
WHERE athleteId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT votesForId FROM athlete)
```